# Vue : How to use the values of mapState earlier than mounted hook?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to use the values of mapState earlier than mounted hook, so that I can use the value of 'authority', if 'authority' is 1 then I'll use function `getUserList`, else then I'll use function `getUserSingle`.

But I couldn't use it like this. Which ways can I use to use mapState values earlier?

```html
<template>
  <table v-if="authority==1">
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>department</th>
      <th>authority</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(data, i) in userList" :key="i">
      <td>{{ data.idx }}</td>
      <td>{{ moment(data.create_dt).format('YYYY.MM.DD') }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.username }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.account }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.mobileNo }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.department }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.authority === 1 ? 'admin' : 'user' }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table v-else>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>department</th>
      <th>authority</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(data, i) in userSingle" :key="i">
      <td>{{ data.idx }}</td>
      <td>{{ moment(data.create_dt).format('YYYY.MM.DD') }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.username }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.account }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.mobileNo }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.department }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.authority === 1 ? 'admin' : 'user' }}</td>
      
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import { fetchUserList, fetchUserSingle } from '@/api/index'
export default{
  data() {
    return {
      moment: moment,
      userList: [],
      userSingle: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$bus.$on('closeModal', () => {
      if(this.authority == 1){
        this.getUserList()
      }else{
        this.getUserSingle(this.idx)  // this.idx from mapState
      }
      this.closeModal()
    })
    if(this.authority == 1){
      this.getUserList()
    }else{
      this.getUserSingle(this.idx)  // this.idx from mapState
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('store', {
      idx: (state) => state.id,
      authority: (state) => state.authority,
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    getUserList() {
      fetchUserList().then((res) => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          this.userList = res.data
        } else {
          return alert(res.data.message)
        }
      })
    },
    getUserSingle(idx) {
      fetchUserSingle(idx).then((res) => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          this.userSingle = res.data
        } else {
          return alert(res.data.message)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `created()` runs before `mounted()` though I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking

Comment: I meant of that I want to call the values of 'state' earlier than mounted. Can I call the state values in created hook?

Comment: You can't. you should move your code to watchers instead. If you can't because of the `closeModal` event, you may have to change your flow.

Comment: The question is more, why would you need to access it earlier? This should not be an issue. Especially since `computed` get's re-evaluated when it's value is updated. Please give us the actual problem rather than asking for your approach of a solution.

Comment: No I think you were misreading, his computed properties get re-evaluated every time, but not the methods getUserList() and getUserSingle() themselves which were called once during the mounted hook and every time the event 'closeModal' is emitted. I suppose that he needs to execute either one of these methods to fetch the data accordingly at the beginning of the component life circle

Comment: Oh yeah right, indeed! Moving it away or watching for those may be a good idea indeed. Also, please check the lifecycle of Nuxt if you do feel the need: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't painted a full picture where you get the `authority` value from, but I'm assuming that you get it from an API, then later store it the `store` (state, Vuex). If that's the case, then it has nothing to do with the `mounted hook` itself. It really depends on your internet connection, sometimes it comes before `mounted`, sometimes after. We'll never know. In this kind of situation, there are two solutions I can think of:

1. If this component is a child of another one, in other words, not attach directly to the current route. You can place a `v-if="authority !== null"` on this component in the parent component. Obviously you've got to initialize `authority = null` at the beginning.

Like so:

```
<parent-component>
  <this-component v-if="authority !== null" />

</parent-component>
```

By doing this, this child component will only start its life circle when the `authority` becomes available (0 or 1 I assume, just not `null`). V-if will delay your component to be rendered until the expression return `true`, then you can safely rely on the `mounted` hook, or even the `created` hook in this specific case.

2. If this component is not a child of any component, you've got to use the dynamic watcher `vm.$watch` in `mounted` hook (or `created`, doesn't matter here). Then start watching the computed property `authority`, and tear down this watcher after the first run.

Example:

```
mounted() {
  this.$bus.$on('closeModal', () => {
      if(this.authority === 1){
        this.getUserList()
      }else{
        this.getUserSingle(this.idx)  // this.idx from mapState
      }
      this.closeModal()
  })

  // sometimes `authority` is available in `mounted`, then do the work

   if(this.authority === 1){
      this.getUserList()
    }else if (this.authority === 0) {
      this.getUserSingle(this.idx)  // this.idx from mapState
    } else { 

      // in case it's not ready yet, set up watcher
      const unwatch = this.$watcher('authority', () => {
      if (this.authority === null) return

      if(this.authority === 1){
        this.getUserList()
      }else{
        this.getUserSingle(this.idx)  // this.idx from mapState
      }

       unwatch() // this is how you tear down this watcher after first run
     })

   }


}
```

Anyway, it looks like you need to do some code refactoring right there. Probably wrap the logic in a function then reuse it.